# Where should I store my tokens in Android?

Tags: android

In my application I'm storing my token to access a web service in the *strings.xml*, but now I want to commit it (Github) without the token value.

Comment: what about saving it to  Shared Preferences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: I'm going to commit the code and I can not figure out a way to use SharedPreferences without exposing my token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be focused on the version control issue. If having that token in `res/values/strings.xml` is working for you, then you can put the token value in `gradle.properties` (e.g., as `WEB_SERVICE_TOKEN`), and the generate the corresponding string resource from Gradle using `resValue`:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    resValue "string", "whatever_your_string_resource_is_called", WEB_SERVICE_TOKEN
  }
}
```

This will create a string resource named `whatever_your_string_resource_is_called`, containing the value you gave `WEB_SERVICE_TOKEN` in `gradle.properties`. Then, exclude `gradle.properties` from your version control system (e.g., via `.gitignore`).

The bigger issue is: should your Web service token actually be in your APK? After all, [you are leaking that token to anyone who wants to get it](http://www.zdnet.com/article/secret-tokens-found-hard-coded-in-hundreds-of-android-apps). Depending upon the nature of your app and the nature of this Web service that you are trying to access, you might try alternatives to using a string resource, such as:

- Not using the Web service from the app, but rather from your own Web service (e.g., one that the user has to log into)
- Using the Web service from the app, but securely downloading the token and storing it on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (so only those who root their devices can get the token)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I'm using https://www.themoviedb.org token to list the movies. There is no way to use my own web service or download the token.